# Speeding up newton-raphson in pandas/python

Tags: python, pandas, newtons-method

I'm currently iterating through a very large set of data ~85GB (~600M lines) and simply using newton-raphson to compute a new parameter. As of right now my code is extremely slow, any tips on how to speed it up? The methods from BSCallClass & BSPutClass are closed-form, so there's nothing really to speed up there. Thanks.

```
class NewtonRaphson:

    def __init__(self, theObject):
        self.theObject = theObject

    def solve(self, Target, Start, Tolerance, maxiter=500):
        y = self.theObject.Price(Start)
        x = Start
        i = 0
        while (abs(y - Target) > Tolerance):
            i += 1
            d = self.theObject.Vega(x)
            x += (Target - y) / d
            y = self.theObject.Price(x)
            if i > maxiter:
                x = nan
                break
        return x

    def main():
        for row in a.iterrows():
            print row[1]["X.1"]
            T = (row[1]["X.7"] - row[1]["X.8"]).days
            Spot = row[1]["X.2"]
            Strike = row[1]["X.9"]
            MktPrice = abs(row[1]["X.10"]-row[1]["X.11"])/2
            CPflag = row[1]["X.6"]

            if CPflag == 'call':
                option = BSCallClass(0, 0, T, Spot, Strike)
            elif CPflag == 'put':
                option = BSPutClass(0, 0, T, Spot, Strike)

            a["X.15"][row[0]] = NewtonRaphson(option).solve(MktPrice, .05, .0001)
```

EDIT:

For those curious, I ended up speeding this entire process significantly by using the scipy suggestion, as well as using the multiprocessing module.

Comment: Iterating row-by-row is not especially efficient since Series objects have to be created.

Comment: So I'm not exactly sure how to vectorize this, that's the thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't code your own Newton-Raphson method in Python. You'll get better performance using one of the [root finders in scipy.optimize](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/optimize.html#root-finding) such as [brentq](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.brentq.html#scipy.optimize.brentq) or [newton](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.newton.html#scipy.optimize.newton).
(Presumably, if you have `pandas`, you'd also install `scipy`.)

---

Back of the envelope calculation:

Making 600M calls to brentq should be manageable on standard hardware:

```
import scipy.optimize as optimize
def f(x):
    return x**2 - 2

In [28]: %timeit optimize.brentq(f, 0, 10)
100000 loops, best of 3: 4.86 us per loop
```

So if each call to `optimize.brentq` takes 4.86 microseconds, 600M calls will take about 4.86 * 600  ~ 3000 seconds ~ 1 hour.

---

`newton` may be slower, but still manageable:

```
def f(x):
    return x**2 - 2
def fprime(x):
    return 2*x

In [40]: %timeit optimize.newton(f, 10, fprime)
100000 loops, best of 3: 8.22 us per loop
```

Comment: So AFAIK, you're unable to set the target w/ scipy's newton function. The results were less than satisfactory using brentq (I whipped something up last night using it).

Comment: The `Target` is just a constant, so instead of trying to find the root for  `f(x) = 0`, you'd define `g(x) = f(x) - Target` and apply `newton` to `g`.